# TYPO3: Migrating fe_users realurl configuration to routeEnhancers

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x, realurl

TYPO3: Migrating fe_users realurl configuration to routeEnhancers

At the moment I am updating TYPO3 from version 8 to 9. Up to now I have used `ext:realurl` to generate speaking urls. Now I am struggeling to get the "old" urls to work with the new routeEnhancers.

I have extendend the `fe_users` table in an own extension with the field `my_department`. Now I am trying to get the URLs with the following routeEnhancers to work.

```
routeEnhancers:
  FeusersPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyFeusers
    plugin: Users
    #limitToPages: [3,7]
    defaultController: 'FrontendUser::list'
    defaults:
      company_title: ''
      department_title: ''
    routes:
      # Detail view:
      -
        routePath: '/{employee_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::show'
        _arguments: {'employee_title': 'frontendUser'}
      # List view
      -
        routePath: '{company_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::list'
        _arguments: {'company_title': 'company'}
      -
        routePath: 'department/{department_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::list'
        _arguments: {'department_title': 'department'}
    aspects:
      employee_title:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: fe_users
        routeFieldPattern: '^(?P<first_name>.+)-(?P<last_name>\d+)$'
        routeFieldResult: '{first_name}-{last_name}'
      company_title:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          name-of-company: 'Name of company'
          name-of-other-company: 'Name of other company'
      department_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'fe_users'
        routeFieldName: 'my_department'
```

**Not working part:**
`/?tx_myfeusers_users[action]=list&tx_myfeusers_users[company]=Name of company&tx_myfeusers_users[controller]=FrontendUser&tx_myfeusers_users[department]=My department`

=> result: `/department/My%20department/?tx_myfeusers_users[company]==Name%20of%20company`
=> desired: `name-of-company/department/My%20department/`
  => or even better `name-of-company/department/My-department/`
  => or even much better `name-of-company/My-department/`

**Working parts:**
`/?tx_myfeusers_users[action]=list&tx_myfeusers_users[company]=Name of company&tx_myfeusers_users[controller]=FrontendUser`
=> result: `/name-of-company/`
=> desired: `/name-of-company/` => perfect!

`/?tx_myfeusers_users[action]=show&tx_myfeusers_users[controller]=FrontendUser&tx_myfeusers_users[frontendUser]=143`
=> result: `/firstname-lastname/`
=> desired: `/firstname-lastname/` => perfect!

This is my realurl config, which was working for me:

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(

  'userDetailConfiguration' => array(

    array(
      'GETvar' => 'tx_myfeusers_users[company]',
      'valueMap' => array(
        'name-of-company' => 'Name of company',
        'name-of-other-company' => 'Name of other company'
      ),
      'noMatch' => 'bypass'
    ),
    array(
      'GETvar' => 'tx_myfeusers_users[action]',
      'valueMap' => array(
        'show' => '',
        'list' => '',
        'edit' => 'edit',
        'update' => 'update',
      ),
      'noMatch' => 'bypass'
    ),
    array(
      'GETvar' => 'tx_myfeusers_users[controller]',
      'valueMap' => array(
        'FrontendUser' => '',
      ),
      'noMatch' => 'bypass'
    ),
    array(
      'GETvar' => 'tx_myfeusers_users[frontendUser]',
      'lookUpTable' => array(
        'table' => 'fe_users',
        'id_field' => 'uid',
        'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(first_name, "-", last_name)',
        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
          'strtolower' => 1,
          'spaceCharacter' => '-',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  '3' => 'userDetailConfiguration',

),
'postVarSets' => array(
  '_DEFAULT' => array(

    'department' => array(
      array(
        'GETvar' => 'tx_myfeusers_users[department]',
      ),
    ),

  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find another way to get it working, I wrote my own mapper for the department:

Register the mapper in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']
        ['SYS']
        ['routing']
        ['aspects']
        ['DepartmentStaticMapper'] = \Vendor\Extension\Routing\Aspect\DepartmentStaticMapper::class;
```

Add the file for the mapper class in `Classes/Routing/Aspect/DepartmentStaticMapper.php`. The mapper does nothing, but returns the given value:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticMappableAspectInterface;

class DepartmentStaticMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $settings;

    /**
     * @param array $settings
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function __construct(array $settings)
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And finally use the mapper `DepartmentStaticMapper` in the `routeEnhancers` of your site configuration (last line of the following config):

```
routeEnhancers:
  FeusersPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyFeusers
    plugin: Users
    #limitToPages: [3,7]
    defaultController: 'FrontendUser::list'
    defaults:
      company_title: ''
      department_title: ''
    routes:
      # Detail view:
      -
        routePath: '{employee_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::show'
        _arguments: {'employee_title': 'frontendUser'}
      # List view
      -
        routePath: '{company_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::list'
        _arguments: {'company_title': 'company'}
      -
        routePath: 'department/{department_title}'
        _controller: 'FrontendUser::list'
        _arguments: {'department_title': 'department'}
    aspects:
      employee_title:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: fe_users
        routeFieldPattern: '^(?P<first_name>.+)-(?P<last_name>.+)$'
        routeFieldResult: '{first_name}-{last_name}'
      company_title:
        type: StaticValueMapper
        map:
          name-of-company: 'Name of company'
          name-of-other-company: 'Name of other company'
      department_title:
        type: DepartmentStaticMapper
```